# Writing information from files into an archive file?

Tags: c, buffer, printf

I'm a relatively decent Java programmer, but completely new to C. Thus some of these functions, pointers, etc are giving me some trouble...

I'm trying to create an archive file (I'm basically re-writing the ar sys call).  I can fstat the files I want, store the necessary information into a struct I've defined. But now comes my trouble. I want to write the struct to the archive file. So I was thinking I could use `sprintf()` to put my struct into a buffer and then just write the buffer.

```
sprintf(stat_buffer, "%s", file_struct);
write(fd, stat_buffer, 60);
```

This doesn't appear to work. I can tell the size of the archive file is increasing by the desired 60 bytes, but if I `cat` the file, it prints nonsense.

Also, trying to write the actual contents of the file isn't working either...

```
    while (iosize = read(fd2, text_buffer, 512) > 0) {
        write(fd, text_buffer, iosize);
        if (iosize == -1) {
            perror("read");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

I'm sure this is a relatively easy fix, just curious as to what it is!

Thanks!

Comment: after write(), the i/o buffer is not flushed. so try fflush(), whenever you want to peek into the file from outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%s` is used to print string. So sprint will stop when it will meet a `\0` character.

Instead, you could directly write your structure to your file. `write(fd, &file_struct, sizeof(filestruct));` but you wont be able to read it with a cat call. You still can, from another unarchiver program, read the file content and store it to a structure `read(fd, &filestruct, sizeof(filestruct));`

This system is not perfect anyways, because it will store the structure using your computer [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and wont be portable. If you want to do it right, check out the [ar file format specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_%28Unix%29#File_format_details).

Comment: I've developed my struct to be exactly as it's defined in ar. Your write call you gave me gave the following error at compile time:
error: incompatible type for argument 2 of write
/usr/include/unistd.h:363:16: note: expected const void * but argument is of type struct file_struct

Comment: I forgot to put a & sign. Write 2nd argument is a pointer to the memory fragment you want to write to your file. The 3rd one will give the number of memory bytes needed.